# Why do strings appear as numbers in shiny dropdown menu?

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny

I have a .txt file containing the following four lines:

*Country1

Country4

Country2

Country3*

I want these lines to be automatically read into a drop-down-menu.

Here's my code so far:

UI:

```
selectizeInput("drop",("Select country"), choices 
 =read.table('countries.txt', header=FALSE, sep='\t')[1], selected = 1)
```

All I get is a drop-down-menu with the choices of "1","4","2" and "3", but not the strings "Country1", "Country4","Country2" or "Country3".

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings are being imported as factors.  Add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your `read.table` function.